# Google chrome extension issue: popup.html interferes with script execution in background.html

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am learning how to extend Google chrome and I have run into the following problem:

I have the following manifest file:

```
{
    "name": "My First Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "The first extension that I made.",
    "background_page": "background.html",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png", 
        "popup": "popup.html"
     },
    "permissions": [
    "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ]
 }
```

My background.html file just injects some simple JavaScript into the page:

```
<script>
    // Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:"alert(\"hi from background CODE\");"});
    });
</script>
```

My popup.html file is just simple HTML:

```
<body>
    Sup Playa
</body>
```

The dialog box from background.html never gets displayed. popup.html functions as expected.

However when I comment out popup.html from the manifest file, the script in background.html works.

What am I doing wrong? Why aren't both the dialog box and the popup showing up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it says in the [docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/browserAction.html):

> `onClicked` event will not fire if the browser action has a popup.

So if you assign any html file to your popup `"popup": "popup.html"` (rather than just a button without body), `onClicked` event isn't fired.

You can just put your code right into `popup.html` (it has same privileges as a background page) if you want something to be executed each time it is opened:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:"alert(\"hi from background CODE\");"});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. So basically you have to make a design decision about whether it makes sense to have the execution take place in popup.html or background.html, but you can't have it in both places.

Comment: @Mitya You can execute in both places, just you can't listen to `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` as it won't fire if browser action has a popup.